# How to catch http requests type "Other" in Safari by Javascript

Tags: javascript, safari, webrequest

I want to catch all request in my App to handle error.
In Chrome, Edge, the requests is only xhr or fetch. I can do this.
But in Safari, sometime the type is "**other**". I can't find any documentation for this.
Can anyone please advise me solution to track these request type "other" in Safari?
My app code is Javascript
Thank you.

[image]